# PHP form validation not processing correctly

Tags: php, forms, validation

Having an issue with a form with PHP validation.

The form works fine without validation--the information gets populated to our database. The validation actually appears to work fine, however when submitting, the information does not get properly processed to the database.

I am very new to this, so I apologize in advance and would appreciate any help.

**PHP validation script:**

```
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $validForm = true;
    $errors = array();

    if (empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
        $validForm = false;
        $errors['first_name'] = true;
    }

    if (empty($_POST['last_name'])) {
        $validForm = false;
        $errors['last_name'] = true;
    }

    if (empty($_POST['email_address']) || strpos($_POST['email_address'], '@') === false) {
        $validForm = false;
        $errors['email_address'] = true;
    }

    if (empty($_POST['cust_group'])) {
        $validForm = false;
        $errors['cust_group'] = true;
    }

    if ($validForm) {
    header('Location:http://oi.vresp.com?fid=2b68154d4e');
    exit();
  }
}
?>
```

**HTML form:**

```
    <table>


        <?php if (!empty($errors)): ?>

        <div style="color:red;font-family:'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;"> 

          <?php if (!empty($errors['first_name'])): ?>
          Please enter your first name.<br />
          <?php endif; ?>

          <?php if (!empty($errors['last_name'])): ?>
          Please enter your last name.<br />
          <?php endif; ?>

          <?php if (!empty($errors['email_address'])): ?>
          Please enter a valid email address.<br />
          <?php endif; ?>

          <?php if (!empty($errors['cust_group'])): ?>
          Please select customer type.<br />
          <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

<form id="signupForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">

<tr>
  <td>

  <div align="right">

  <span style="color: #666; font-size:10px; text-decoration:none; font-style:italic;">All fields are required.</span>

  </div>

  </td>
</tr>
<tr<?php echo (isset($errors['first_name'])?' style="color:red;"':'') ?>><td>

  <div id="inputArea" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11.5px; font-style:bold;"> 
            <label for="first_name" class="formLabel">First Name</label><br />
           <input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" <?php echo (isset($_POST['first_name'])?" value=\"$_POST[first_name]\"":'') ?>/>

  </div>

</td>
  </tr>

<tr<?php echo (isset($errors['last_name'])?' style="color:red;"':'') ?>><td>

  <div id="inputArea" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11.5px;">
    <label for="last_name" class="formLabel">Last Name</label><br />
        <input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" <?php echo (isset($_POST['last_name'])?" value=\"$_POST[last_name]\"":'') ?>/>

  </div>

</td>
  </tr>

<tr <?php echo (isset($errors['email_address'])?' style="color:red;"':'') ?>><td>

  <div id="inputArea" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11.5px;">

    <label for="email_address" class="formLabel">Email</label><br />
        <input name="email_address" type="text" id="email_address" <?php echo (isset($_POST['email_address'])?" value=\"$_POST[email_address]\"":'') ?>/>

  </div>

</td>
  </tr>

<tr<?php echo (isset($errors['cust_group'])?' style="color:red;"':'') ?>><td>

<div>

    <label for="cust_group" class="formLabel">Customer Type</label><br />
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" onClick="toggle('q1')" style="color: #666; text-decoration:none; vertical-align:middle;" <?php echo (isset($_POST['cust_group'])?" value=\"$_POST[cust_group]\"":'') ?>><span id="selectBtn">Please select customer type &#9662; </span></a>

</div>

<div id="q1" style="display:none;">

    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="Architect/Designer" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'Architect/Designer')?" checked":'') ?>> Architect/Designer<br>
    </label>

    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="AV/Media/Broadcast" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'AV/Media/Broadcast')?" checked":'') ?>> AV/Media/Broadcast<br>
    </label>

    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="Command/Control" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'Command/Control')?" checked":'') ?>> Command/Control<br>
    </label>

    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="Distributor - Office/Office Furniture" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'Distributor - Office/Office')?" checked":'') ?>> Distributor - Office/Office Furniture<br>

    <label>  
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="Education" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'Education')?" checked":'') ?>> Education<br>

    <label>  
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="End User" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'End User')?" checked":'') ?>> End User<br>
    </label>

    <label>  
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="Financial/Trading" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'Financial/Trading')?" checked":'') ?>> Financial/Trading<br>
    </label>

    <label>  
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="Gaming" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'Gaming')?" checked":'') ?>> Gaming<br>
    </label>

    <label>  
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="Government" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'Government')?" checked":'') ?>> Government<br>
    </label>

    <label>  
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="Hospitality" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'Hospitality')?" checked":'') ?>> Hospitality<br>
    </label>

    <label>  
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="Integrator/Installer" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'Integrator/Installer')?" checked":'') ?>> Integrator/Installer<br>
    </label>

    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="Lean Manufacturer" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'Lean Manufacturer')?" checked":'') ?>> Lean Manufacturer<br>
    </label>

    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="OEM - General" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'OEM - General')?" checked":'') ?>> OEM - General<br>
    </label>

    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="OEM - Healthcare" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'OEM - Healthcare')?" checked":'') ?>> OEM - Healthcare<br>
    </label>

    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="OEM - Office" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'OEM - Office')?" checked":'') ?>> OEM - Office<br>
    </label>

    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="POS/Digital Display/Kiosk" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'POS/Digital Display/Kiosk')?" checked":'') ?>> POS/Digital Display/Kiosk<br>
    </label>

    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="Web Retailer" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'Web Retailer')?" checked":'') ?>> Web Retailer<br>
    </label>

    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="cust_group" id="cust_group" value="Other" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['cust_group']) && $_POST['cust_group'] == 'Other')?" checked":'') ?>> Other<br> 
    </label>

</div>

  <tr><td>
  <input type="hidden" value="true" name=optin> 
  <input type=hidden name=form_submitted value=1>
  <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" border=0 value="Subscribe"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: Where's the database part?

Comment: The information entered in this form gets sent to a third party, our email marketing database.

Comment: You stated that the validation works properly. So I guess you are using header() to send the information?

Comment: To clarify, validation works as intended--as it will prompt the user to enter in the required information. Yes, the header() sends the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function is used to send HTTP response headers back to the user. Don't use it to create request headers.

You'll have to look at [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php) ([see examples](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/simplepost.html)).

For instance, instead of :

```
header('Location:http://oi.vresp.com?fid=2b68154d4e');
```

You'll have to use cURL :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://oi.vresp.com?fid=2b68154d4e');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'first_name='.$firstName.'&last_name='.$lastName...........);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. As a newbie though, I have no idea how to implement this. Does the entire form need to be recreated or is it a matter of simply replacing the header() function?

Comment: Thank you again. Was getting errors so changed the code to the below, and it appears to work fine now:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "first_name=$first_name&last_name=$last_name&email_address=$email_address&cust_group=.$custGroup.");`

However, upon submitting the form, the confirmation page now loads above the form...how do I get the confirmation page to display on its own?

Removed the previous exit(); function because it would not allow the page to load...

Comment: After curl_close, you can redirect the user to your confirmation page. If my answer solved your issue, consider accepting. If you have further issues with curl, please open an other question.

Answer (score 0):

You better have to check an array like this

```
if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 1) {
```

Comment: This does not solve OP's issue since "validation appears to work fine".